# Using Function while assigning Formula

Tags: excel, vba

I try to assign a formula to a cell via an Macro in Excel:

```
Worksheets("Jan").Cells(30,J).Formula= "=ADDRESS(24;3)"
```

This doesn't work. Assigning a formula like `"=1+1"` works.

The strange thing is, when i enter the above formula directly in Excel to a cell it works. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have a couple of problems in that line of code.
Unless `J` is a variable not shown,`.Cells(30,J)` should be `.Cells(30, "J")`

Also, `"=ADDRESS(24;3)"` should be `"=ADDRESS(24,3)"`. You separate the values with a comma, not a semicolon.

Comment: Are there any reasons why in a macro i have to use a comma and in Excel a semicolon?

Comment: I'm using excel 2010 and using a semicolon in excel results an in error. Are you sure the semicolon was working for you in excel?

Comment: Its because .Formula uses USA rules for separators etc regardless of your Locale settings

Comment: @CharlesWilliams ahh. Learned something!

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use something like this:
'Worksheets("Jan").Cells(30,"J").Value= "=ADDRESS(24,3)"'

This approach will put the *string* "=ADDRESS(24,3)" into the cell that you've specified.

Does that do what you want?

---

Update: 
1) Looks like others have correctly identified and resolved the real problem: the Locale setting issue. 
2) [Microsoft help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa221602%28v=office.11%29.aspx) also showed me that the '.formula' addressing is the correct way to input a formula, so my suggestion may be useful as a troubleshooting step but isn't the best way to go about this.